# Issue in android TextView with accented letters

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am using accented letters in android textview but on some devices letters are not positioned as expected here is screen shot of two different devices first sony xperia c [image]

which is correct but in LG nexus 4 e960 accented a is not positioned correctly see below screen

[image]

textview code in xml

```
<com.driver.test.widget.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="¿Ya estás \nmatriculado \nen alguna \nautoescuela?"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

How to tackle this issue ?

Comment: Is the behavior same for the default textview that is provided by android?

Comment: @PrerakSola not tested with default textview. If you need i will post my customtextview class also

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the next properties?

```
    android:lines="4"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
```

That may be the problem..